# Create a list item and specify its GUID

Tags: 2013, list, splistitem, guid

I'm aware that (integer) ID can't be specified for a list item when it gets created (and why), but it seems like there should be a way for a client to specify the GUID for an item it is creating. This way it doesn't need to re-query in order to know what the item is.

Have I missed some documentation about this or some reason it's not an available feature in sharepoint?

Comment: Why specify the GUID? Using the SPList.AddItem method returns a SPListItem anyway so you don't need to get it again...

Comment: Hi @Bunzab E.g. Preparing data offline for migration into lists that have lookup relationships. Ideal to specify IDs on parent items and specify these IDs when preparing data for the lookup property on child items. Better not to have to do the migration in multiple steps.

Comment: It is enormously beneficial for clients to be able to specify guids on created items.  Platforms should allow this wherever possible.  It avoids having to requery and it lends to the writing of simpler app logic.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to set the Item ID value in SharePoint. We can make false the read-only field and set the value of ID.

pleas check the below post for your reference.
http://sharepointwalkers.blogspot.in/2012/04/insert-item-in-sharepoint-list-with.html

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check this out